# Solving a differential equation by substitution method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the equation
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{2t+y-1}-2$$
Knowing that $y(0)=1$, and using a substitution the form $v=at+by+c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if we set $v(t)=2t+y(t)-1$ then we have that
$$v'=2+y'$$
and thus $y'=v'-2$. Making substitutions we have
$$y'=e^{2t+y-1}-2\to v'-2=e^v-2$$
which reduces to $v'=e^v$ which is separable differential equation with solution
$$\int e^{-v}dv=-e^{-v}=\int dt=t-C$$
Hence
$$v=-\ln(C-t)\to 2t+y(t)-1=-\ln(C-t)$$
giving $y(t)=1-2t-\ln(C-t)$. Then computing $y(0)$ we have $y(0)=1-\ln(C)=1$ therefore $C=1$ finally yielding
$$y(t)=1-2t-\ln(1-t)$$

Answer (score 1):

setting $$v=2t+y-1$$ we get $$v'=2+y'$$ thus we have $$v'-2=e^v-2$$ and we have to solve
$$v'=e^v$$
can you proceed?